# Why am I getting NoSuchBeanDefinitionException in my implementation of LogoutSuccessHandler

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security and so far I managed to make the login part work, but as to the log out I tried to implement LogoutSuccessHandler only to get the exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter] while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'customLogoutSuccesHandler' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'customLogoutSuccesHandler' is defined
```

Here's what I've done:

web.xml:

```
<!-- ================== SPRING SECURITY ===================== -->

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/config/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/config/applicationContext-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- ================== LOGIN-CONFIG ===================== -->

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>

    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login/login.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<!-- ================== ERROR-PAGE ===================== -->

<error-page>
    <error-code>400</error-code>
    <location>/common/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/common/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/common/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/common/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<!-- ================== WELCOME-FILE-LIST ===================== -->

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Then I added this at applicationContext.xml:

```
    <bean id="customLogoutSuccessHandler" class="com.wplex.info.error.CustomLogoutSuccessHandler" />
```

And my applicatonContext-security.xml is like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<b:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http>
        <intercept-url pattern="/register/**" access="ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/monitor/**" access="ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/operation/**" access="ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/register/companyList.jsp" access="ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR" />

        <form-login login-page="/login/login.jsp"
            always-use-default-target="true" 
            authentication-success-handler-ref="loginSuccessHandler"
            />
        <logout logout-url="/login/login.jsp" success-handler-ref="customLogoutSuccesHandler" />
        <remember-me />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="WplexInfoDS_Translitoral"
                authorities-by-username-query="SELECT u.username, p.role 
                                             FROM users u, users_role p 
                                            WHERE u.id = p.id_user 
                                              AND u.username = ?"
                users-by-username-query="SELECT username, password, 1
                                       FROM users 
                                      WHERE username = ?" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</b:beans>
```

CustomLogoutSuccessHandler.java

```
public class CustomLogoutSuccessHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler
{

    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
        final HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, final Authentication authentication)
        throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        if (authentication != null && authentication.getDetails() != null)
        {
            try
            {
                httpServletRequest.getSession().invalidate();
                System.out.println("User Successfully Logout");
            }
            catch (final Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        //redirect to login
        httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/login/login.jsp");
    }
}
```

Comment: typo... `customLogoutSuccessHandler` is the actual name, not `customLogoutSuccesHandler`...

Comment: @M.Deinum Very good eyes

Comment: @M.Deinum Goddammit, I looked so hard for typos, only to miss this one. Thanks, man.